# STM32F103 USB Packet Memory Corruption

Tags: stm32

Writing a USB driver for the "Blue Pill" - sub $2 board from China.

The STM32F103 has a USM packet memory of 512 bytes.  The USB sees this memory as 256 words.  The Application has to access this memory on 32bit boundaries so I us DW access.

As a test - a wrote a data pattern into the array then read it out to verify its contents.  I found many single bit failures.

Has anyone experienced this?

I'm wondering if China may be using ST parts that did not past all of ST's MFG testing and the one I got had issues with this memory array.

Any comments?  My recourse right now is to scrap the board.

Thanks

Comment: First check if your code is responsible for the errors. Flash the stm32duino bootloader, and see if the board is programmable with arduino ide. I assume it will fail if the IC is bad.

Comment: Thanks but I don't use Arduino for anything.  I've been hand crafting code for 40 years now.

Comment: I didn't mean to make you use it, just run the code that was tested on thousands of boards out there, and see if that's really the chip responsible for errors.

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://kevincuzner.com/2018/01/29/bare-metal-stm32-writing-a-usb-driver/) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a cloned STM32 part.

Some of them have missing features, and some have even fixed problems with the original (debug). Another $2 board from the same supplier may well behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there a lot of [fake STM32F103 chips](https://github.com/keirf/Greaseweazle/wiki/STM32-Fakes) on the China's market. Several Chinese firms make "almost completely identical" F103 chips but with their own design ([GD32F103](https://www.gigadevice.com/products/microcontrollers/gd32/arm-cortex-m3/mainstream-line/gd32f103-series/), [CS32F103](https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/02/10/cs32-mcu-stm32-clone-bluepill-board/) and so on).

Many of them are [selling with fake STM markings](https://embeddedtronicsblog.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/fake-stm32-blue-pill-boards/), creating appearance that they are original STM chips (possibly, lacking of STM logo, but not necessarily; different font etc).

So, you can never be sure. The *budgetary* price of original STM32F103 is [about $2.05 itself for minimal order of 10k units](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f103c8.html), so it's hard to expect original chips on these Chinese $2.00 Blue-pill boards with a lot of other components.

On the other hands, this fake STM32F103 can work without problems on 95-99% of tasks.

2. Known problem with USB drivers on STM32 device is small default Heap size of 0x200 in provided linker scripts. Try to increase it according to your needs.